# sqrt Matlab and C++ numerical differences

Tags: c++, matlab, math, precision, scientific-computing

I witness numerical differences between Matlab and C++ code. Discrepancy seems to stem from different output for sqrt method in Matlab and C++. For very small numbers (< 10-5) it seems that relative difference is quite big.

Which approach would you suggest to

1. make sure differences come from sqrt
2. tune the cpp code as to replicate to float precision the Matlab code

EDIT

I add more precision about the code.

```
float* buttonVar = new float[nBut];


for (int_T ibut = 0; ibut < nBut; ibut++)
{
    for (int_T id = start_idx; id <= stop_idx; id++)
    {
        inputArray[id - start_idx] = arr[ibut * nDepth + id];
    }
    reduceVector(inputArray, reducedArray, inputarray_size, d1, d2);

    buttonMean[ibut] = 0;
    buttonVar[ibut] = 0;
    for (int_T id = 0; id < min(nd, nDepth); id++)
    {
        buttonMean[ibut] += reducedArray[id] / float(nd);
    }
    for (int_T id = 0; id < min(nd, nDepth); id++)
    {
        buttonVar[ibut] += (reducedArray[id] - buttonMean[ibut])
                                        *(reducedArray[id] - buttonMean[ibut]);
    }


    buttonVar[ibut] = sqrtf(buttonVar[ibut] / float(nd));
}
```

In Matlab, I am converting to `single` the number to be `sqrt`. Discrepancy in the code appears in `buttonVar`.

Final results that are compared in Google Tests are results from several more operations with no other call to mathematics functions. These additional operations are in methods which were thouroughly Google Tested, and there is perfect match to float precision of outputs for these tests.

Numerical difference in `buttonVar` is up to 15% relative difference (=100*abs(cpp_res - matlab_res)/matlab_res. Significant relative difference occurs when `buttonVar` his of order of magnitude 10e-6.

Comment: float or double?

Comment: please post a MCVE in both MATLAB and C++ and give the numerical results of your comparison.

Comment: It's not surprising to see small numerical differences between languages for operations like `sqrt`, but you need specify exactly what what code you're using and what values cause the problem.

Comment: @horchler  edited the post with more details. thank you for your comments

Comment: please state the range of your values and observed differences (matlab vs. native): it's quite possible, that matlab uses double-precision sqrt even on your `single`s.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios added details on the differences

Comment: Please provide a specific value where the "relative difference is quite big". And show your Matlab code that you're comparing this to.

Comment: also provide a comparison between matlab and using the native double-precision sqrt, to rule out matlab simply upcasting to double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to double in C++ inside the computation solves the difference problem. We reach a very satisfactory match after converting to double.